# What URL should I use with React Native Playground app?

Tags: ios, react-native

I've installed ReactNative Playground from AppStore, trying to figure out, what Development Server url should I use to make this thing work?

- My phone is on the same WiFi
- dev server is browsable, available through http and running with $ react-native start
- I can open http://192.168.X.X:8080/ from my phone
- I can open http://192.168.X.X:8080/index.ios.js from my phone

The thing is, http://192.168.X.X:8080/index.ios.js returns ES6 non-transformed code, and RNPlay raises redbox with "Unexpected use of reserved word 'import'"

Thanks!

Comment: Do you actually need the React native playground? If you can run your app on your device, why try the RNPlayground?

Comment: @JayGarcia, for iOS it needs provisional certificate, and I haven't got one yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, hopefully.

- check your react-native version to be compatible with RNPlay
- for v0.24.1 use this url: http://192.168.1.X:8081/index.ios.bundle

If you need to check out specific version of React Native, use [rninit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rninit) package:

```
$ rninit init [Project Name] --source react-native@0.24.1
```

Don't forget, that RNPlay is bundled with some native packages, thus, you cannot use custom ones, only js-packages.